# how do i filter a dataframe based on the values of a column in another dataframe in R?

Tags: r

For example I have a dataframe --

```
ad

key   value
ab      1
bc      2
cd      3

ad1

key  QS IS LISR Group version
ab    7 23  77    2    1.2
bc    7 30  70    1    1.5
cd    8 40  60    2    1.4
de    6 12  88    3    1.7
ef    3 23  77    4    1.2
fg    2 34  66    2    1.4
```

Result should be--

```
result

key  QS IS LISR Group version
ab    7 23  77    2    1.2
bc    7 30  70    1    1.5
cd    8 40  60    2    1.4
```

I have found some examples,but those are for small dataframes, both of my dataframes are large!

Trying to write a query but didn't work out? How could you solve this?

thanks!

Comment: Try `subset(ad1, key %in% ad$key)`

Comment: Is the value column supposed to have any influence on the output?

Comment: sorry the column name key is different in dataframes, however it worked out with your suggestion(i just changed the names of columns) result<-(ad1,key1 %in% ad$key)

Comment: If the column name is different, use that column name in the `subset`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `%in%` and `subset` to subset the rows in 'ad1' based on the 'key' columns in both the datasets.

```
subset(ad1, key %in% ad$key)
#   key QS IS LISR Group version
#1  ab  7 23   77     2     1.2
#2  bc  7 30   70     1     1.5
#3  cd  8 40   60     2     1.4
```

Or another option is `join` from `data.table`.  In the devel version, we can use `on`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(ad1)`) and join the 'ad' dataset.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(ad1)[ad['key'], on='key']
#  key QS IS LISR Group version
#1:  ab  7 23   77     2     1.2
#2:  bc  7 30   70     1     1.5
#3:  cd  8 40   60     2     1.4
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
ad1[which(ad1$key %in% ad$key),]
```

Comment: "The Lord Gave, and the Lord Hath Taken Away." (c: